# working with ajax variables and post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following ajax function:

```
$("#signInButton2").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {couponcode: $('#couponCode').val(), userEmail: $('#login-username').val() },
    url: 'coursePayment.php',
    success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for    your example it's "bye bye"

    }
   });
});
```

My problem are as follow:

1. It does not seem to post anything to the coursePayment.php
2. userEmail can be refered in both the login-username and the registration, username, how do i associate both id with the userEmail variable
3. essentially similar to point 2. I have couponCodeRegisterAmount and I have couponCodeLoginAmount ID that I would like to associate with one post variable called couponCodeAmount, and which I would like to be able to retrieve on the coursePayment page

For any clarification, let me know thanks

Update HTML

```
<input type="text" oninput="calculate()" name="couponCode"  id="couponCode"  value="" placeholder="Please Enter Coupon Code" required>


<?php ?>
<script>
$("#signInButton2").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {couponcode: $('#couponCode').val(), userEmail: $('#login-username').val() },
    url: 'coursePayment.php',
    success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for    your example it's "bye bye"

    }
   });
});

 </script>

<div class="container">    
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title"><h4><b>Sign In to Proceed with Purchase</b></h4></div>
                    <h4 id="loginError" style="color:red;"></h4>


                    </div>     
                        <h4>   Don't have an account! 
                                        <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                            Sign Up Here
                                        </a></h4>

                    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                        <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>


                        <form method="post" action="">  
                            <!--Coupon Code -->
                        <input type="hidden" id="couponCodeLogin" name="couponCodeLogin">
                             <input type="hidden" id="couponCodeLoginAmount" name="couponCodeLoginAmount">   

                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="" placeholder="username or email">                                        
                                    </div>

                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="password">
                                    </div>



                            <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                          <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                        </label>
                                        <label><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></label>

                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                      <input id="signInButton2" class="btn btn-danger" name="login" type="submit" value="Sign In">

                                    </div>
                                </div>



                            </form>     



                        </div>                     
                    </div>  
        </div>



        <div id="signupbox" style="display:none; margin-top:50px" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title"><h4>Sign Up</h4></div>
                        <h4 id="registerError" style="color:red;"></h4>

                            <div style="float:right; font-size: 85%; position: relative; top: -35px"><a id="signinlink" href="#" onclick="$('#signupbox').hide(); $('#loginbox').show()"><h4>Sign In</h4></a></div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="panel-body" >
                            <form id="signupform" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                                <div id="signupalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p>Error:</p>
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>

                                <input type="hidden" id="couponCodeRegister" name="couponCodeRegister">
                             <input type="hidden" id="couponCodeRegisterAmount" name="couponCodeRegisterAmount">




                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstname" class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" id="emailSignup" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Phone Number</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pnumber" placeholder="Phone Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="icode" class="col-md-3 control-label">Company Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cname" placeholder="Company Name (Optional)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="icode" class="col-md-3 control-label">Position</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cposition" placeholder="Position (Optional)">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->                                        
                                    <div >
                                        <input id="signInButton" class="btn btn-danger" name="register" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div style="border-top: 1px solid #999; padding-top:20px"  class="form-group">



                                </div>



                            </form>
                         </div>
                    </div>



               </div> 
         </div> 
     <!-- register -->
```

Comment: please post your html form

Comment: make sure your jQuery must be under `$(document).ready(function(){ //your code  })` ?

Comment: @user3907211 try adding `"dataType": 'json',`

Comment: thanks for your comments. i added the html portion

Comment: Is that the order in which you have the code? Because if it is, @Noman is correct and you should place that script in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`, otherwise the event binding will happen before the element is generated. Or optionally, you could change the binding to `$("body").on("click", "#signInButton2", function() {` instead of `$("#signInButton2").click(function() {`